# Query on pipe creation between two descriptors of parent-child process

Tags: c, linux, unix

In my below working program, I would like to understand,

How/who established(created) a single pipe communication between {child's pair[1]} descriptor and {parent's pair[0]} descriptor?

Because in my below program, i just fork()'d a process and immediately who has established pipe connection between {child's pair[1]} descriptor and {parent's pair[0]} descriptor?  Do you think it is obvious to accept this point?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   int main(void)
   {
   int pair[2];
   char buf[30] ="";
   pipe(pair);
   if (!fork()) {
          printf(" CHILD: writing to the pipe\n");
          write(pair[1], "test", 5);
          printf(" CHILD: exiting\n");
          exit(0);
   } else {
          printf("PARENT: reading from pipe\n");
          read(pair[0], buf, 5);
          wait(NULL);
          printf(" PARENT: exiting\n");
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions are not particularly clear; the second "question" says something looks obvious, but appears to contain no question itself. For instance, you don't actually say what is going wrong in the samples you have presented (if anything).

I think what you what to know might be as follows:

1. `pipe()` creates two file descriptors which are linked within the operating system, a reader and a writer.
2. When you `fork()` all open FDs are available in both the parent and the child. So if you have called `pipe()` prior to the `fork()`, both the reader and the writer will be available to the child.
3. As normally the parent will be the reader and the child the writer, *or* the parent will be the writer and the child the reader (i.e. neither will both write and read), it is normal for the parent to close one fd and the child to close the other.

Comment: Another point is, 

looks like with the help of pipe() api in  Below program, establishment of pipe communication between pair[1](as writer) and pair[0](as reader), looks obvious to me.


      

     #include <stdio.h>
           #include <stdlib.h>
           #include <errno.h>
           #include <sys/types.h>
           #include <unistd.h>
           int main(void)
           {
           int pair[2];
           char buf[30] ="";
           pipe(pair);
           write(pair[1], "test", 5);
           read(pair[0], buf, 5);
           printf("%s",buf);
           
           return 0;
   }

Comment: abligh:    let me paste the question that i asked above.                          How/who established(created) a single pipe communication between {child's pair[1]} descriptor and {parent's pair[0]} descriptor?

Because in my below program, i just fork()'d a process and immediately who has established pipe connection between {child's pair[1]} descriptor and {parent's pair[0]} descriptor? Do you think it is obvious to accept this point?

Comment: The `pipe` call established that communication between the parent's `pair[1]` descriptor and the parent's `pair[0]` descriptor. The `fork()` then makes a child, and it's `pair[1]` descriptor (and for that matter `pair[0]` descriptor but that is not relevant) is shared with its parent's. So therefore the child's `pair[1]` is connected to the parent's `pair[0]` through the pipe. I'm not sure what you mean by 'do you think it is obvious'. It's obvious to someone who has been doing C socket programming for 20 years, but perhaps not to a newcomer; no shame in things not being obvious.

Comment: Please confirm, if my understanding is correct, if i run pipe(pfds), in a program where we are not creating child process, i think pipe() api creates and opens a temporary file on disk and uses open() api to return write access level file descriptor to pfds[1] and read access level file descriptor to pfds[0].         NOW if i run fork() in the program these two descriptors duplicate in child process and  point to that same temporary file stored in hard disk. so from temporary file perspective, we have two write descriptors and two read descriptors. correct?

Comment: Under Linux (and any version of Unix I know of) creating a pipe does NOT create a temporary file. It creates a pipe.